# Loading a string in a variable instead of the name of the variable (R)

Tags: string, r, variables, load

I am trying to load data frames that are saved in a certain folder. I have a bash script that loops along all `*.gzip` files in the folder and passes the file names as arguments to an R script (`blah.r $file_name`). Now, in the R script, the file name is saved as

```
file_name = commandArgs(TRUE)[1]
```

and it prints the correct file name. However, when I try to load the file

```
data(file_name)
```

R thinks that file_name is a string, not a variable, so it says that it can't find `"file_name"`.

How can I get R to recognize this variable as a variable and not a literal string?

Comment: This isn't a duplicate of the older question. That one was about accessing a variable given its name; this one is about reading a dataset from disk. Thus, `get(*)` isn't applicable here.

Comment: @HongOoi: great catch. Voted to reopen.

Comment: You don't load data into R using the `data()` function. That is for loading example data from installed packages.

Answer (score 2):

The Answer to this the question asked is along the lines of

```
 read.table(file = file_name, ....)
```

where `....` are additional arguments to specify the nature of the text file containing the data you wish to load.

If the data are not in a text file but in some other, possibly binary, format then you will need to use the correct function to import those data. For example, if the data are stored in one of R's formats (via `save()` or `saveRDS()`) then:

```
load(file = file_name) ## for save()-ed objects

foo <- readRDS(file = file_name) ## for objects serialised via saveRDS()
```

You mention the files are `*.gzip`. If so, then see `?connections` and the `gzip()` function, which can also be passed an object containing the file name to open as in:

```
gzip(file_name, ....)
```

where `....` again are further arguments you may need to specify (read the help page).